# Plotting bar plot in Seaborn Python with rotated xlabels

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, seaborn

How can I plot a simple bar graph in Seaborn without any statistics? The data set is simply names and values.

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame({"name": ["Bob Johnson", "Mary Cramer", "Joe Ellis"], "vals": [1,2,3]})
```

I would like to plot this as a bar graph with xlabels pulled from `name` column and y-axis values from `vals` and have x-axis labels rotated 45 degrees. How can it be done? Using `sns.barplot` like:

```
sns.barplot(x="name", y="vals", data=df)
```

will compute statistics that are not relevant here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You mean like that (**set_xticklabels** approach):

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({"name": ["Bob Johnson", "Mary Cramer", "Joe Ellis"], "vals": [1,2,3]})
g = sns.barplot(x='name', y='vals', data=df)
g.set_xticklabels(g.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45)
```

---

Or probably **plt.xticks** approach can help:

```
import pandas
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

df = pandas.DataFrame({"name": ["Bob Johnson", "Mary Cramer", "Joe Ellis"], "vals": [1,2,3]})

bar_plot = sns.barplot(x='name', y='vals', data=df)
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.show()
```